# awk print number of row only in uniq column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have data set like this:

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
2 A
2 B
2 C
3 B
3 C
```

And I have a script which calculates me:

1. Number of occurrences in searching string
2. Number of rows

   ```
   awk -v search="A" \
      'BEGIN{count=0} $2 == search {count++} END{print count "\n" NR}' input
   ```

That works perfectly fine.

I would like to add to my `awk` one liner number of unique lines from the first column.

So the output should be separated by *\n*:

```
2
8
3
```

I can do this in separate `awk` code, but I am not able to integrate it to my original `awk` code.

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a){print i}}' input  | wc -l
```

Any idea how to integrate it in one `awk` solution without piping ?

Comment: right - it is fixed. Number 8 it comes from awk script - NR - it is a number of all rows.

Comment: Number 2 is occurrences in second column "A" (there is twice), and number 3 is the example - unique first column and calculated number of rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want this:

```
awk -v search="A" '{a[$1]++} 
                   $2 == search {count++}
                   END{OFS="\n";print count+0, NR, length(a)}' file
```

Comment: Did not realized to use length(a) :)